# DAX First date by user based on date from other table

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff

I have two tables:

1. **Session**
   Userid
   Sessionid
   Sessiontime
2. **Command**
   Sessionid
   Commandtime

There are multiple commands/commandtimes in one session and I've linked these tables on sessionid.

I am trying to find out the difference between the first sessiontime and the first commandtime for each user.
I'm taking advice of kin sang and providing sample data:

So if the data I have (after joining the tables) looks like:

```
userid: 1 , sessionid: 1, sessiontime: 12.47, commandtime: 12.58
userid: 1 , sessionid: 1, sessiontime: 12.47, commandtime: 12.53
userid: 1 , sessionid: 2, sessiontime: 1.15, commandtime: 1.16
userid: 1 , sessionid: 2, sessiontime: 1.15, commandtime: 1.34
```

I want to isolate the first sessiontime (12.47) and the first commandtime (12.53) and then find the difference between them (6 minutes)

In the actual data, there will of course be multiple userid's. I want to find that time difference for each user id.

Using:

`calculate(Min(session[sessiontime]),allexcept(session,session[userid]))`

I can successfully get a calculated column showing first sessiontime for each user.

However because the commandtime is in a different table to userid, the same formula doesn't work.

Please help me find a way to find the time difference for each user, either via this method or a more efficient one.

Comment: You may need to share sample data with expected output for better understanding

Comment: You need some kind of command identifier to be able to choose the first one. Not even using the FIRSTNONBLANK function on multiple commands with the same session identifier will you be able to define which CommandTime comes first. So far your model allows you to choose the command with the shortest or longest time. Not the first one within the same session.

Comment: Kin Siang, I've added some sample data- does that make it easy enough to understand now or is there something else I can do?